# What happens to the ViewState when I click back on the browser?

Tags: asp.net, browser, viewstate

I'm curious to know what happens to the ViewState on the browse back button.

Does it stay or does the page make a new request?

Answer (score 1):

Viewstate remains no more .NET implementation once it render to html , they become the normal hidden field sitting in the html of the page. So when you do the browse back button , in most of the time we get the page from the Cache of the browser , there will be no request to server. There is no way only ViewState will update itself without refreshing the page , because at the end of the day Viewstate nothing but some hidden field .